# Trying to compress a sentence and then uploading it to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a sentence and I'm trying essentially to compress it. Then I have to upload it to an external file. My sentence has to be uploaded and so does my compressed sentence in another file.

This is my program...

```
word_dictionary = {} 
highest = 0 
sentence = "This is a sentence and is not a very long sentence".split()
s= "This is a sentence and is not a very long sentence"
compressed = []
new = ""
for word in sentence:
    if word not in word_dictionary:
        highest += 1 
    compressed.append(word_dictionary.setdefault(highest, new))

print(word_dictionary)

word_dictionary = str(word_dictionary)

fo = open("index","a+")
fo.write(word_dictionary)
fo.close()

fo=open("sentence","a+")
fo.write(s)
fo.close()
```

What I want to be uploaded into the files would be...

for "index" ---> 1,2,3,4,5,2,6,3,7,8,4

for "sentence" ---> "This is a sentence and is not a very long sentence"

Please help, thanks

Comment: "Please help" _with what_? What's wrong with the code you have? What results is it generating that don't match your expectations?

Comment: It is saving 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 to "index" and not "1,2,3,4,5,2,6,3,7,8,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, i modified your original code and remove `highest` and `word_dictionary`, it works by appending the element `index + 1` if it occurs more than once in the sentence, else it appends the highest number in the list `another` if it's count is less than 1, i also had to initialize `another` with 0 to avoid `max()` throwing an exception for the first element

```
sentence = "This is a sentence and is not a very long sentence"
s = sentence.split()
another = [0]

for i in s:
    if s.count(i) < 2:
        another.append(max(another) + 1)
    else:
        another.append(s.index(i) +1)

another.remove(0)

fo = open("index","w")
for index in another:
    fo.write(str(index))
fo.close()

fo=open("sentence", "w")
fo.write(sentence)
fo.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you test for:

```
if word not in word_dictionary:
...
```

but you never save any word in the dictionary, instead you save that `highest` counter:

```
compressed.append(word_dictionary.setdefault(highest, new))
```

so `word` will never be in `word_dictionary` and `highest` will always be incremented.

Comment: This might sound a bit stupid... but I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me here

Comment: the reason you expect `1,2,3,4,5,2,6,3,7,8,4` as output, is because "is" is the 2nd and 6th word, hence the `2` in the 2nd and 6th positions. To achieve that you must 'remember' the first position of each new word that you encounter, you're not doing that. I get the feeling that you don't fully understand the compression algorithm you're trying to implement, maybe try a pen and paper example before coding it.